# Torch7: Addition layer with Tensors of inconsistent size like numpy

Tags: numpy, torch

I would like to add two tensors with one different dimmension.

For example:

```
x = torch.ones(4,5)
y = torch.ones(4,3,5)
```

In numpy I'm cappable of doing this with:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.ones((4,5))
y = np.ones((4,3,5))
y + x[:,None,:]

#Prints out
array([[[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]],

   [[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]],

   [[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]],

   [[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]]])

It has a shape of (4,3,5)
```

Is there any way to reproduce this on a `nn.CMulTable()`? When I view `x` tensor like this `x:view(4,1,5)` it give me an error `inconsistent tensor size`.

```
m = nn.CAddTable()
m:forward({y, x:view(4,1,5)})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [expandAs](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#result-expandasresult-tensor) to obtain a 4x3x5 tensor:

```
m:forward({y, x:view(4,1,5):expandAs(y)})
```